# Qt не находит файлы

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Проблема заключается в том что Qt не замечает файлы, даже те, которые созданы в папках проекта.

Приведу пример:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFile file("text.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Error", "Error: Cannot open file", QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Ok);
    } else {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QString str = stream.readAll();
        qDebug() << str;
        file.close();
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Здесь файл text.txt создан в той же папке что и файл исходного кода. Однако Qt не удается открыть этот файл и выскакивает ошибка `QMessageBox::critical`. Однако если указать полный путь из корневой папки, то тогда все будет работать нормально.
Можно было бы использовать и так, указывая абсолютный путь к файлу. Однако будет много костылей в большом проекте при его переносе на другое устройство.

Comment: А если в папку к экзешнику поместить?

Comment: @timur заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете установить рабочий каталог во вкладке `Проекты -> Запуск` на необходимую вам папку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]